# Running Flower using Supervisor

Tags: python, celery, flower

Am having challanges starting flower using supervisor.

The following command in my development environment works on the console

`celery --app=celery_conf.celeryapp flower --conf=flowerconfig`

but moving to production to use supervisor am getting all sorts of errors

**/supervisor/conf.d/flower.conf**

```
[program:flower]
command=/opt/apps/venv/my_app/bin/celery flower --app=celery_conf.celeryapp --conf=flowerconfig
directory=/opt/apps/my_app
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=false
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/flower.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/flower.out.log
```

With the above configuration, there is no error but all celery does is give me a help like output. Its like it doesn't acknowledge the variables passed.

```
 Type 'celery <command> --help' for help using a specific command.
 Usage: celery <command> [options]
 Show help screen and exit.
 Options:
   -A APP, --app=APP     app instance to use (e.g. module.attr_name)
   -b BROKER, --broker=BROKER
                         url to broker.  default is 'amqp://guest@localhost//'
   --loader=LOADER       name of custom loader class to use.
   etc..
   etc..
   etc...
```

Supervisor on the other hand throws `INFO exited: flower (exit status 64; not expected)`

I have other supervisor initiated apps using `celery_beat` and using the [configuration file samples on github](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/3.1/extra/supervisord/celerybeat.conf) and they are working well with the same directory paths as above

The flowerconfig is as below:

**flowerconfig.py**

```
# Broker settings
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'

# RabbitMQ management api
broker_api = 'http://guest:guest@localhost:15672/api/'

#Port
port = 5555

# Enable debug logging
logging = 'INFO'
```

**Solution:**

Well, not really a solution so I haven't put it as an answer. Turned out there was a problem with my virtual environment. So I removed flower and installed again using pip3.4 as am on python3.4

Something to note though is that for flower to use your `flowerconfig` file, you need to add a `director=/path/to/your/celery_config/folder/` entry in supervisor's `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/flower.conf` file else flower will launch with default settings.

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/flower.conf**

```
; ==================================
;  Flower: For monitoring Celery
; ==================================
[program:flower]
command=/opt/apps/venv/my_app/bin/celery flower --app=celery_conf.celeryapp --conf=flowerconfig
directory=/opt/apps/my_app/celery_conf #this is key as my configuration file was in the `celery_conf` folder
user=www-data
autostart=true
autorestart=false
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery/flower.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery/flower.out.log
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your supervisor is unable to locate `celeryapp`. My be your supervisor configuration file `supervisor.conf` is in different path.

You can pass `directory` option to supervisor process. So you can try

```
[program:flower]
directory = /opt/apps/venv/my_app/
command =  celery --app=celery_conf.celeryapp flower
```

This starts a new flower instance.

Also note [celery conf](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html#configuration) and [flower conf](http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html) are different.

Comment: Looks like you answered as I was editing the question. I think I resolved the path errors. Now all am getting is `help like` output from celery with the new configuration. Note that I have two directories `opt/apps/venv/my_app` which is the virtual environment for the application and also `/opt/apps/my_app` which is where the application resides..

Comment: does your command works correctly on the command line? what do you have in your flowerconfig?

Comment: Yes it works fine. The flowerconfig has got basic settings. I've added the settings to the question..

Comment: Turned out there was a problem with the virtual environment installation. I've posted final working conf file

Comment: Where can I find `flowerconfig.py` file.?

Comment: @AlbinAntony You have to create one.